# Scale results in paraview

Tags: python, paraview

The results I get in paraview through the generated .vtu files are too small (eg magnitude of ^-18) this is because I run an analysis through a scaled down model.

I would like to give the results in a exagerated form so that deflection and stresses are very visible. So I need to multiply my results with a factor.

Can I do this in the paraview interface or should I find a way to write the .vtu files with a magnification factor.

A method to do either would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Calculator filter (http://daac.hpc.mil/software/ParaView/ParaView_Calculator.html) can be use to multiply an array by a value. "Result Array Name" should be set to a new, unique name.

Comment: Worked a treat mate. Thanks